# Заключение в кавычки т. н. подлинных выражений

Tags: прямая-речь, пунктуация

Нужно ли заключать в кавычки фразу: "Все течет, все изменяется". Если она идет в прямой речи непосредственно перед вопросом?

Answer (score 1):

В приведенном примере кавычки не нужны.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Обычно  выражение «Все течет, все изменяется» включается в различные тексты без кавычек, например:

Да, всё течёт, всё изменяется, нельзя дважды вступить в один и тот же эшелон.

Ваша убежденность в неизменяемость Веры вступает в противоречие с тезисом, что все течет все изменяется.

С другой ― весело булькал-журчал ручей, как бы приговаривая: жизнь не кончилась, все течет, все изменяется.

2) Чтобы поставить кавычки  фраза должна  иметь приложение, например:

Первая часть фразы "все течет, все изменяется", вырванная из авторского контекста, обрела изначальную законченность.

«Все течет, все изменяется»― под этот рефрен мы изучали марксизм, и в частности истмат.

По его мнению, идея «все течет, все изменяется» есть именно осознание начала истории.

Answer (score 0):

Слова прямой речи заключаются в кавычки. А что значит непосредственно перед вопросом?

Comment: Это часть вопроса из интервью:
– Все течет, все изменяется. Что бы Вы хотели отметить из развития компании за прошедшее время? Какие принципиально важные события произошли?

Comment: Да, кавычки нужны. Но. Если данное предложение в самом интервью, то кавычки не нужны. Интервью обычно оформляется в виде диалога. Но если предложение вырвано из текста интервью( т.е. - это цитата), то кавычки нужны.

Comment: Интервью там оформлено в виде диалога и это один из вопросов. Т.е. я так поняла, что в данном случае кавычки не нужны?

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли.